# Given a pre-order binary tree visit construct a binary search tree with the same pre-order visit. (if possible)

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, preorder

Im trying to solve this problem:" A binary tree is given, check his pre-order visit and build a binary search tree with the same pre-order visit. Demonstrate if it is always possible, if not give an example when this is not possible."
Any help? I need to write pseudocode and give time complexity but i have a lot of doubts about building a binary-search-tree with the same pre-order visit for every possible binary tree.

Comment: Try to look at the problem from different point of view - answer the following question: when given pre-order traverse of binary search tree - can I draw the tree? Can I draw another?

Comment: @ReinhardMänner yeah i know, i was searching only some tips.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the classic algorithm for inserting in a binary search tree, that is, to perform a search and on the found `NULL` pointer where the search was stopped to put the new node, then just to insert in an empty tree the preorder sequence will produce exactly a binary tree with exactly the given preorder sequence.

Just try. Traverse any preorder sequence and insert it in an empty tree and you will realize it.

I hope to help you. And welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.