# Program to create tree from inorder and preorder traversals(iterative approach?)

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, iteration, binary-tree

I have been trying to write a program to create tree from given inorder and preorder char arrays. I can do that through recursive program easily. But I am not able to convert it in an iterative approach. Please somebody,help me with this.

Code.

```
    public BinaryTreeNode<char> ConstructTree(char[] preorder, char[] inorder, int start, int end)
            {
             Dictionary<char,int> InorderKeys = StoreInorderKeys(inorder);
                if(start>end)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                char key = preorder[preIndex];
                preIndex++;
                BinaryTreeNode<char> tr = new BinaryTreeNode<char>(key);
                if (start == end)
                {
                    return tr;
                }
                int rootNodeKey = InorderKeys[key] 
                tr.left = ConstructTree(preorder, inorder, start, (rootNodeKey - 1));
                tr.right = ConstructTree(preorder, inorder, rootNodeKey + 1, end);
                return tr;
            }  
     private Dictionary<char,int> StoreInorderKeys(char[] inorder)
            {
                Dictionary<char, int> d = new Dictionary<char, int>();
                for(int i=0;i<inorder.Length;i++)
                {
                    d[inorder[i]] = i;
                }
                return d;
            }
```

Comment: same class as Samuel? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170577/given-a-pre-order-binary-tree-visit-construct-a-binary-search-tree-with-the-same

Comment: @Aldert yes same, but I want a iterative approach to this question and not recursive.

Comment: @RahulRanjan are you asking for `Binary Search tree` or `Binary tree`? Because your tag says binary-tree.

Comment: for binary-tree @vivek_23

Comment: @RahulRanjan Does the tree have duplicate values?

Comment: @vivek_23 no, it does not have duplicate values. My inorder and preorder arrays are as follows--
 char[] inorder = (new List<char>() { 'F','B','A','E','H','C','D','I','G'})
 char[] preorder = (new List<char>() { 'H', 'B', 'F', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'I' })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment that

```
char[] inorder = (new List<char>() { 'F','B','A','E','H','C','D','I','G'}) 
char[] preorder = (new List<char>() { 'H', 'B', 'F', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'I' })
```

particularly the fact that `inorder` is not sroted suggest that you actually use an unsorted ["Binary Tree"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) instead of the ["Binary Search tree"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) that my original answer implied.

So how to build a binary tree that matches given `inorder` and `preorder`? The idea is based on properties of the `preorder` and `inorder` for the binary search tree mentioned in the original answer. Particularly:

- If you insert values into a BST in an order the come in the `preorder`, you will get a tree with that preorder
- For a BST inorder traverses the nodes in the sorting order

So an easy way to build such a BT is to build it as a BST inserting the values in the order of the `preorder` and (here is the tricky bit) using the `inorder` as their sorting order. In other words you forget about any "natural" sorting and use a fake one that exactly reflects the `inorder`.

The outer iteration is obviously iterative. Typical insert value implementation is tail recursive so it is easy to convert it into an iterative code as well. Here is full code:

```
class BinaryTreeNode<T>
{
    public readonly T value;
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> left = null;
    public BinaryTreeNode<T> right = null;

    public BinaryTreeNode(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void InsertValue(T newValue, Comparer<T> comparer)
    {
        InsertValueNR(this, newValue, comparer);
    }

    private static void InsertValueNR(BinaryTreeNode<T> start, T newValue, Comparer<T> comparer)
    {
        for (BinaryTreeNode<T> cur = start; ;)
        {
            int cmp = comparer.Compare(cur.value, newValue);
            if (cmp == 0)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("value '" + newValue + "' is duplicated in the tree");
            else if (cmp < 0)
            {
                if (cur.left == null)
                {
                    cur.left = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(newValue);
                    return;
                }
                else
                    cur = cur.left;
            }
            else
            {
                if (cur.right == null)
                {
                    cur.right = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(newValue);
                    return;
                }
                else
                    cur = cur.right;
            }

        }

    }

    private void InsertValueRecursive(T newValue, Comparer<T> comparer)
    {
        int cmp = comparer.Compare(value, newValue);
        if (cmp == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("value '" + newValue + "' is duplicated in the tree");
        else if (cmp < 0)
        {
            if (left != null)
                left.InsertValueRecursive(newValue, comparer);
            else
                left = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(newValue);
        }
        else
        {
            if (right != null)
                right.InsertValueRecursive(newValue, comparer);
            else
                right = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(newValue);
        }
    }



    class OrderComparer<T> : Comparer<T>
    {
        private readonly Dictionary<T, int> positions;

        public OrderComparer(List<T> order)
        {
            positions = new Dictionary<T, int>();
            for (int i = 0; i < order.Count; i++)
            {
                positions[order[i]] = i;
            }
        }

        public override int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            return -Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(positions[x], positions[y]);
        }
    }

    public static BinaryTreeNode<T> ConstructTree(List<T> preorder, List<T> inorder)
    {
        var comparer = new OrderComparer<T>(inorder);
        var root = new BinaryTreeNode<T>(preorder[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < preorder.Count; i++)
        {
            root.InsertValue(preorder[i], comparer);
        }

        return root;
    }

    public void PrintPreOrder()
    {
        PreOrder(ch => Console.Write(ch + " "));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void PrintInOrder()
    {
        InOrder(ch => Console.Write(ch + " "));
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    public void PreOrder(Action<T> visitor)
    {
        visitor(value);
        if (left != null)
            left.PreOrder(visitor);
        if (right != null)
            right.PreOrder(visitor);
    }

    public void InOrder(Action<T> visitor)
    {
        if (left != null)
            left.InOrder(visitor);
        visitor(value);
        if (right != null)
            right.InOrder(visitor);
    }

}
```

The most important part of it is a custom `OrderComparer` that is used instead of the "natural" `char` order. Also I left both non-recursive `InsertValueNR` and recursive `InsertValueRecursive` to illustrate how easy it is convert the later into the former.

Test example:

```
var inorder = new List<char>() { 'F', 'B', 'A', 'E', 'H', 'C', 'D', 'I', 'G' };
var preorder = new List<char>() { 'H', 'B', 'F', 'E', 'A', 'C', 'D', 'G', 'I' };
var root = BinaryTreeNode<char>.ConstructTree(preorder, inorder);
root.PrintInOrder();
root.PrintPreOrder();
```

I get

> F B A E H C D I G 
>   H B F E A C D G I

---

## Original Answer (for BST)

**Note**: This initial answer assumed that the term ["Binary Tree"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) here actually means ["Binary Search tree"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) i.e. a sorted one.

Are you sure that you want to build a tree from pre-order and inorder at the same time? If you look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54172197/182660) in the linked question, you may find that the pre-order alone fully specifies the tree: you just do usual inserts into the tree of the data in the order you are given. Then you can only check if it matches the given inorder or not. You can't build any other tree with the same pre-order. But actually you can just check whether the inorder is sorted or not: if it is sorted - it will match. If it is not sorted - it is not a valid inorder for any tree.

As for inorder, there is a very simple way to build a very inefficient but still technically valid binary tree: put the first value into the root and then add every next value as its right child. This tree obviously matches the inorder. This is effectively the same as building the tree using the inorder as its pre-order.

Actually you can just make any random shuffle of the data in the inorder array and insert them in that order (as if it was a pre-order). The thing is that any valid binary tree with the same contents (i.e. the same set of values in all nodes but possible different inner structure) will have the same inorder just by definition of the inorder.

Comment: Apparently, the OP wants it for a binary tree. `You can't build any other tree with the same pre-order.`. I tend to disagree. For example- `[10,20]` can have `20` as either left child or right child of `10`. Both tree states are valid.

Comment: @vivek_23, sorry but I must disagree. Given that the OP agreed to be in the same class as [the referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170577/given-a-pre-order-binary-tree-visit-construct-a-binary-search-tree-with-the-same) "binary tree" most probably means "binary _search_ tree" which means that `20` has to go on the right of `10`. Also "in-order" for non-BST makes little sense to me.

Comment: Well, I confirmed the same from OP and he agrees to binary tree and not binary search tree(as discussed in the comments). You may edit your answer accordingly though for binary tree.